# Checking for specific cases when turning over 52 cards in shuffled order

Tags: python

There are 52 cards in a deck I am trying to have it where it will go through each card which is random, so a shuffled deck of 52 cards then for the first case it will find 2 aces once it finds that it will loop out and print how many cards it took to do so. 
Then another function for checking the next for 5 spades to do the same 
Then another function for the 13 hearts

So it'll be 3 separate functions where the first function will be `def 2aces()` checking for the 2 aces 
`def 5spades` checking for the 5 spades
`def 13hearts` checking for the 13 hearts

So by changing `len(set(card.suit for card in hand)) == 1) to equal the conditions of either`
 `2 aces` or `5 spades` or `13 hearts`
Which can just be made into 3 separate functions.

The problem here is I would need to do it where its a shuffled deck of 52 cards. So I would traverse through the deck as an example using a for loop and checking the statement. But I'm not sure how to do so with suits and card.

As for the condition with 13 hearts, thats why I want to shuffle a deck of 52 cards then use a for statement to check each element in the list so if its a heart pull it out until all 13 hearts are pulled out or flipped over. Then once you find 13 cards of hearts which is Ace through King in all hearts, then it breaks and says how many cards it took to reach that point.

```
2 aces 
5 spades
13 hearts
```

So no matter what you would have to use object-oriented, classifying the suit then number?
I am trying to see what is the best way to go about this

Once I can do that I just have to print the expected number of cards it takes to flip to get one of those options.

I have a program that prints out if it is a flush using object-oriented but I'm not sure how to tailor it to make it to other specific options. I can edit it to put it in here to see if I can modify that.

Here is a example i used to find if the cards were a flush

```
from collections import namedtuple
from random import shuffle

Card = namedtuple("Card", "suit, rank")

class Deck:
    suits = '♦♥♠♣'
    ranks = '23456789JQKA'

    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = [Card(suit, rank) for suit in self.suits for rank in self.ranks]
        shuffle(self.cards)

    def deal(self, amount):
        return tuple(self.cards.pop() for _ in range(amount))
flush = False
count = 0
while not flush:

    deck = Deck()
    while len(deck.cards) > 52:
        hand = deck.deal(52)
        # (Card(suit='♣', rank='7'), Card(suit='♠', rank='2'), Card(suit='♥', rank='4'), Card(suit='♥', rank='K'), Card(suit='♣', rank='3'))

        if len(set(card.suit for card in hand)) == 1:
            print(f"Yay, it's a Flush: {hand}")
            flush = True
            break
        else:
            #print(f"No Flush: {hand}")
            count +=1
print(f'Count is {count}')
```

But this is for 5 cards getting drawn. I want to have it where it traverses through 52 cards that are shuffled then it checks each one and if 2 aces are found it will loop out and say how many cards it took to get 2 aces from the shuffled deck. Then the same for the other options stated above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These should do the trick:

```
def _2_aces():
    deck, counter, draws = Deck(), 0, 0
    while counter < 2:
        draw = deck.deal(1)[0]
        draws += 1
        if draw.rank == 'A':
            counter += 1
    return draws

def _5_spades():
    deck, counter, draws = Deck(), 0, 0
    while counter < 5:
        draw = deck.deal(1)[0]
        draws += 1
        if draw.suit == '♠':
            counter += 1
    return draws

def _13_hearts():
    deck, counter, draws = Deck(), 0, 0
    while counter < 13:
        draw = deck.deal(1)[0]
        draws += 1
        if draw.suit == '♥':
            counter += 1
    return draws
```

Btw, is it intended that `10` / `T` is not in your ranks?

Comment: What do you mean when ```10```/```t```

Comment: I added in your code right under the deal method and deleted the flush portion. Then this error code came ```return tuple(self.cards.pop() for _ in range(amount))
IndexError: pop from empty list```

Comment: @l.m.m The ranks you defined in your `Deck` class don't include the Tens. It skips from 9 to Jack.

Comment: So something is wrong with the return method im assuming

Comment: Oh wow!!! It worked, it was actually what you guys both said. I added in the 10 and all of a sudden the error went away!!!